# wpf gridcontrol bindint to liq to ef query is slow

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, linq, binding, gridcontrol

I have a usercontrol in wpf which contains a gridcontrol
I've set gridcontrol datasource to a linq to ef join query like this:

```
var x = from B in x.B join E in X.E on B.E_ID equals E.E_ID
        select B
gridcontrol.datasource = x.tolist();
```

in xaml code I've set grid control columns as this:

first column `FieldName = ID`

second column `FieldName = E.Name`

since the second column is binded to E table,the gridcontrol loading is awfuly slow

plz give me a solution to increase the speed

Comment: Calling `ToList()` on your query is unnecessary, a collection is a collection and the grid control will know what to do with it. With that said, your query is as basic as it can get. If that's not fast enough for you, you need to consider paging or setting some indices on your databases... the slowness is likely not from your code here.

Comment: thanks friend but i have tested with and without .tolist() and checked many ways.if i delete the second column it works well and gridcontrol load very fast but the problem is i need to show the second column.when i use breakpoint the query return value fastly but the line of code which set gridcontrol datasource takes long time

Comment: @pooooooneh "*when i use breakpoint the query return value fastly*" The query does not execute until you materialize it by either enumerating or calling `ToList` and similar. Also since you are selecting only `B` in the query, I don't see how it helps to get `E.Name`. If `E` is lazy loaded navigation property, you'd better use eager loading (something like `db.B.Include(b => b.E).ToList()`)

Comment: thank you friend lvan Stoev.I used eager loading and the speed get better.Now it take around 8 sec .if i use listbox instead of gridcontrol the it takes half time to load around 4 sec.If you write your tip as an answer i can mark the question as solved.thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with many thanks of lvan Stoev
as he/she said,i changed my query and it was usefull.now it just take 8 second to load the usercontrol.
the query:
db.b.include("E").tolist()